# DestroyJavaVM memory leak

Tags: java, dll

I am attempting to resolve a memory leak. As you can appreciate it is quite an important thing to achieve.

The application in question uses Java in a modular fashion; loading and unloading Java VMs each with their own instance of the DLLs.

Hence the need to use DestroyJavaVM and FreeLibrary.

Before DestroyJavaVM is called all user resources are freed and all user threads terminated.

The issue is that the DLLs are not released with FreeLibrary and hence the memory leak occurs. It is important to note that there is one DLL instance for each JavaVM where no two JavaVMs share the same DLLs. The question is not to ask why but to accept this is a necessity.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the system to release the DLLs after DestroyJavaVM has been called.

Many Thanks
P

Comment: The likeliest scenario is that some other Windows process has *also* opened the same .dll (yes, I know you *think* that's "not supposed to happen" ;)).  SUGGESTION: Fire up [Process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you. It looks like Java is still active even after DestoryJavaVM. Do you know of anyway to ask Java to shutdown? I will search but for now I am thinking of simply terminating the threads and freeing the libraries.

Comment: btw no other processes are working with these files.

Comment: Finally got Java to shutdown. I am so made right now, been working on this for weeks :)